# Robospice in android.os.Service context

Tags: android, service, robospice

According to RoboSpice documentation https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Design-of-RoboSpice , i can use it in any Context.

Can't find an example of using Robospice in service context.
I did some attempts but nothing happened, requests just not executes, no exceptions (Maybe some log leaking, what i need to do to enable robospice log on device?)

1. Where to start/stop it? (spiceManager.start(this) / spiceManager.shouldStop())
2. Where to create SpiceManager instance? (My service starts in application.onCreate() method, maybe i have to wait for some SpiceService initialization?)

some code

```
public abstract class SpicyService extends Service {

    private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(SpiceService.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        spiceManager.start(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        spiceManager.shouldStop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shame on me ...

After drinking some coffee i spotted that child Service, dont have super.onCreate() call to start spiceManager.

It's working perfectly fine now!
Sorry for your time.

Comment: Double check that your onDestroy method is really called. I would stop the spiceManager in onStop.. This one is called for sure !

Comment: android.os.Service doesn't have onStop() method

Comment: Even if it were an activity, `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called either.